# ValueError when converting number to 8-bit format

Tags: python, string, integer

I want to print the binary numbers 0x00 to 0xFF with their full 8-bit format.

The `bin()` Python function won't return the full 8 bits, so I need to use the `format` function to format the binary string.

This code below is giving me a `ValueError`, but I'm passing a binary string to the format function and I'm using `08b` so why is it giving an error?

```
a = bin(10);
a_bin = "{0:08b}".format(a);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bin` will return a string and you cannot format a string as if it were a number. That's why the exception message said that it's an unknown format for **strings**:

```
>>> "{0:08b}".format(bin(10))
ValueError: Unknown format code 'b' for object of type 'str'
```

You have to use the integer as input for format:

```
>>> "{0:08b}".format(10)
'00001010'
```

Comment: I knew it would be something small. Thank you. Still trying to get to grips with this language, the lack of typing throws me off a bit.

Comment: @jm123456 You can always use Mypy for static type checking if you really need it. But it can’t tell you anything different from the TypeError you’re already seeing (and the same would be true even in Haskell or Rust); it would just happen at compile time rather than a fraction of a second later, so in not sure how that would help you.

Comment: @abarnert It's less to do with it actually having a tangible difference with the code I write, but for some reason I feel like mentally my thought patterns are different when I write code in Python than in a typed language such as Java. Since I'm used to strong typing I find it hard to code without it, so it makes writing Python code harder.

Comment: @jm123456 Python _is_ a typed language, and in fact it has much stronger typing than Java, not weaker. The difference is _static_ typing (or static type checking). And, since 3.5, Python is optionally static typed, with Mypy as the "blessed" way to check it. (This happened in large part because Guido discovered that, whether or not static checking is useful for most coding, it's definitely useful for porting 2.7 code to 3.x when it's full of string operations, which happened to be what his team was doing at the time.) Also, many IDEs can now do static fly-checking in Python just like Java.

Comment: @jm123456 You also might want to consider adding a linter like `flake8` to your workflow (maybe with fly-linting) to catch common problems that aren't actually type errors but are still statically detectable. (Python's static typing is more like Java's than Haskell's or Rust's, and doesn't try to represent everything that could reasonably be statically checked, only the kinds of things OO developers tend to think of as types.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the number, not the string:

```
>>> "{0:08b}".format(10)
'00001010'
```

To print all:

```
>>> for i in range(0, 256):
...     print("{0:08b}".format(i))
...
00000000
00000001
00000010
00000011
00000100
...
11111011
11111100
11111101
11111110
11111111
```